# Laravel 6/7 testing: A facade root has not been set

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-7, laravel-testing

I am trying to write some tests for my my Laravel 7 app.
But i keep facing `A facade root has not been set.` error.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AddressListenerRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCreate()
    {
        Config::set('x', 'address_listeners'); // Cause of "A facade root has not been set" error
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain the reason of this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `use Test\TestCase;` instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

The test needs to call the createApplication method, which it's located in `Test\TestCase` and That method will trigger the Kernel so every object and class get bootstrapped. and then you can use the container, facade, request, response and all of that stuff.